# url-loader not working with custom webpack for angular 8

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8, urlloader

I'm using [custom webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) to use webpack with Angular 8, and I want to use [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) to inline SVGs, because the server the app is being deployed to doesn't support the SVG image/svg+xml mimetype (and I can't change that to support it). However when I build the app, the SVGs aren't being inlined.

Angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Emergent-Event": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "less"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/Emergent-Event",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              ...
            ],
            "styles": [
              ...
            ],
            "scripts": [
              ...
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Emergent-Event:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Emergent-Event:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Emergent-Event:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              ...
            ],
            "styles": [
              ...      
            ],
            "scripts": [
              ...
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Emergent-Event:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Emergent-Event:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "Emergent-Event"
}
```

extra-webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(svg)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

I also tried svg-url-loader and svg-inline-loader libraries, but I couldn't get any of them to inline SVGs. I don't know what else to try. Is there something wrong with my configuration, or is Angular doing something I'm not expecting?

Answer (score 0):

By default angular handles it with file-loader.
Example code how to replace file-loader to base64-inline-loader:

```
// your custom webpack config
module.exports = config => {
  config.module.rules = config.module.rules
    .filter(rule => rule.loader !== 'file-loader')
    .concat({
      test: /\.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
      loader: 'base64-inline-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    });

  return config;
};
```

Or you can write code to remove only `svg` from `test` field and add new rule only for it.

Comment: Hm. I tried the base64-inline-loader library just now, with no luck. I've got tomcat configured so that it doesn't recognize the image/svg+xml mimetype to mimic the environment this app is deployed in, and the images still don't load. Inspecting the image area shows it's still loading the actual url and not using a base64 url.